# issue editing xml file in AjaxToolkit HtmlEditorExtender

Tags: xml, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using AjaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender to open edit XML files in my asp.net application, and have come across an issue where my xml nodes are not showing up in my document specifically the ones that begin the node like "< t h i n g s >" or "< s t u f f "

Comment: the quoted stuff got removed  it was "< t h i n g s >" and "< s t u f f". both with no spaces.

Comment: Here's where I stand now. I have a HtmlEditorExtender control that looks like this:

Comment: Here's where I stand now. I have a HtmlEditorExtender control that looks like this:  ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="editorExtender" TargetControlID="txtEditor" DisplaySourceTab="true" runat="server"    I've added to my web.config a configSection for system.web sanitizer and the sanitizer section that points to HtmlAgilityPack dll as the provider. and this entry for the ajaxControlToolkit  ajaxControlToolkit useStaticResources="true" htmlSanitizer="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer, AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer"/> still same result

Answer (score 1):

HtmlEditorExtender uses a Sanitizer by default that removes nodes that are not in a white list. This is expected behavior, because HtmlEditorExtender and Sanitizer are designed for HTML, not XML.

You can disable sanitization by setting `EnableSanitization` property to `false` and try to edit XML files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MikhailTymchukDX, Tried that, EnableSanitization currently causes a Parser error, stating that it is not a public property of the HtmlEditorExtender.

Comment: That's strange. The code obviously shows it is a public property: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/HtmlEditorExtender/HtmlEditorExtender.cs#L147

Comment: Turns out I was having an issue updating my version of AjaxControlToolkit. The project used to run with version 4.1.something, and when I updated to version 16.1.1.0 the .dll file in my projects bin folder was not replaced. I am still having issues getting the sanitizer to work. Now though it doesn't build at all :(

Comment: Did you follow [upgrading guide](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below)?